# How to put integer literals into Room query?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Is it possible to put integer literals into Room query? Following query leads to build error:

```
@Query("UPDATE topics SET unreadCount=0 WHERE id=:chatId")
fun resetUnreadCount(chatId: Long)
```

I have tried several options (including [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery)) and came to an option of passing Int argument with default value:

```
@Query("UPDATE chats SET unreadCount=:ZERO WHERE id=:chatId")
fun resetUnreadCount(chatId: Long, ZERO: Int = 0) // hacky way to pass int literal into the query
```

Is there a normal way to do that?

Comment: What build error are you facing? I have an app with queries similar to your first one that seem to be working just fine.

Comment: Apparently there was some issue in my project, because I just tried to use a 0 literal and it works like expected with both Int, Long and Boolean as well as all nullable types.

Answer (score 1):

First query has a different Entity class 'topics'

```
@Query("UPDATE topics SET unreadCount=0 WHERE id=:chatId")
```

Should it be chats too? as the below query is working. integer in the query is fine.

```
@Query("UPDATE chats SET unreadCount=:ZERO WHERE id=:chatId")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this documentation.

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Look in section 3.4, it talks about coumn affinity behviour

```
unreadCount='0'
```

This should also work

```
@Query("UPDATE topics SET unreadCount='0' WHERE id=:chatId")
```